# Progress Bar loading according to timer

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, android-timepicker

Am using a timer to record video in my App and it is based on JavaCvRecorder app.
When I press the screen the recording starts and we are able to see the time in leftside of screen.
Now instead of showing the timer I have to show a progress bar to load according to the time can any one help me on this as i don't know where to show the progress bar. The below is code for showing time while recording video. Please help me friends

```
private void initiateRecording(boolean isActionDown) {
    isRecordingStarted = true;
    firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    recording = true;
    totalPauseTime = 0;
    pausedTime = 0;

    txtTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Handler to show recoding duration after recording starts

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    btnRecorderControl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnRecorderControl.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.stop));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use AsynkcTask method

private void call_timerprogressbar() { //......call this method first 
        try {
            callprogressbar sessionrunner = new callprogressbar(getActivityTaskHandler);
            sessionrunner.execute();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

public class callprogressbar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Handler statushandler;

        public callprogressbar(Handler getActivityTaskHandler) {
            statushandler = getActivityTaskHandler;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //........call your timer function
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setMessage("Please wait... ");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressBar.setTitle(" ");
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = result;
                statushandler.sendMessage(msg);
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }catch(Exception ex){

            }
        }

    }

    public Handler getActivityTaskHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    };
```